# How do I use C# records with dapper?

Tags: .net, .net-core, dapper

Is there a way to use C# records with dapper as of today? I know I can add a default constructor, but it would be nice if I didn't have to do that.

So what is the state of dapper and records today?

**Update** To clarify. I want to define my dto like

```
public record MyDto(string id, string somethingelse);
```

and be done with it.

Comment: It probably hasn't been tested; it would need looking at

Comment: Seems to be an open issue about it: https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/1571